# TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType problem

Tags: python-3.x, bmi

this is a bmi calculator in toolbox

```
def BMI():
                bmiwin = Tk()
                bmiwin.geometry("300x300")
                bmiwin.title("BMI Calculator")
                Entry1 = Entry(bmiwin).pack()
                Entry2 = Entry(bmiwin).pack()
                
                bmi = Entry1 / m.pow(Entry2,2)
                def result():
                        res = "Your BMI is " + str(bmi)
                        messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)
                bmibutton = Button(bmiwin , text = "Calculate" , command = result).pack()
```

please give me debugged code
what is the problem, Codes must be inside def():

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the text in `Entry`, we use the `.get()` method.

And since math.pow() does not expect String argument, we need to convert it to int

moreover, you need to get the bmi after the button has been pressed, hence it needs to be inside the function

**Corrected code:**

```
def BMI():
                bmiwin = Tk()
                bmiwin.geometry("300x300")
                bmiwin.title("BMI Calculator")
                Entry1 = Entry(bmiwin)
                Entry1.pack()
                Entry2 = Entry(bmiwin)
                Entry2.pack()

                def result():
                        bmi = int(Entry1.get()) / m.pow(int(Entry2.get()),2)
                        res = "Your BMI is " + str(bmi)
                        messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)
                bmibutton = Button(bmiwin , text = "Calculate" , command = result).pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 thing you have to fix:

1. Since we are taking inputs from the variables declare them separately and use .get() method to use the values where required.
2. Conversion of the input to int/float will help to avoid errors when calculating the BMI.
3. We also need to activate the Event Loop for the GUI to execute and user to be able to interact with it.

Here is the code for reference:

```
    def BMI():
        bmiwin = Tk()
        bmiwin.geometry("300x300")
        bmiwin.title("BMI Calculator")

        height = Entry(bmiwin)
        heigth.pack()
        weight = Entry(bmiwin)
        weight.pack()

        def result():
            bmi = float(weight.get()) / m.pow(float(height.get()), 2)
            res = "BMI: " + str(bmi)
            messagebox.showinfo("Result", res)

    bmibutton = Button(bmiwin, text="Calculate", command=result).pack()
    bmiwin.mainloop()
```